# Test automation-How to Generate Result Document

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Can anyone please describe me, how test automation process is done exactly in the industry? And also I want to know ho the test results are document after the execution.For an example; if I automate a log in scenario how should I generate a test result report. For an instance, if the I typed email address and password in invalid format how it generate the result document including used test data, and results according to each result. I'm getting user inputs using Scanner. Then I want to document those entered inputs and particular result and the PASS/FAIL status. I am really new to test automation. I am doing my testing by doing self studying. I really want to know how it happens. Please help me. Thank you

I am using Selenium webdriver with java.

Comment: I think this is off topic here in so. What have you done? There is no single answer to your question. You could start by reading a whole lot of getting started to get the hang of it. As for the result doc: One approach is to use a logger, another to redirect the standard output to a log file or you could generate html code in your text

Comment: Sorry for asking a question which is off topic. And anyway thank you for suggested way for me.I will try it by using logger. Thank you